# Http POST response undefined - how to get an object from controller by using Ok(object) method

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript

I think I have got a newbie question, but I searched over the Internet - no result.
So I'm calling a controller with a POST method with given parameters (weight and height) and I expect to receive a status code Ok(result) with an object inside it.
The method is called properly, I receive sth from the method, but the result is "undefined". I tried to tell the POST method to expect JSON results, by giving a header, but no result. I mean, I receive an Object, but I don't know why it's not mapped correctly and thus, the result is not shown as it should.
I was expecting, that response will be type Result, like in the class defined and I can freely read from it, but no.

That's the response I get

```
{"bmiClassification":0,"result":4.03,"summary":"To be done"}
```

Here is controller class I'm calling BMICalculatorController.cs

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class BMICalculatorController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IBMICalculatorLogic _calculator;
        private readonly ITest _test;
        public BMICalculatorController(IBMICalculatorLogic calculator)
        {
            _calculator = calculator;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("calc")]
        public IActionResult Calculate([FromBody] ParametersDto parameters)
        {
            var result = _calculator.GetResult(parameters.Weight, parameters.Height);
            return Ok(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is typescript component I'm working on:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ParametersDto } from '../models/ParametersDto';
import { Results } from '../models/Results';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bmicalculator',
  templateUrl: './bmicalculator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bmicalculator.component.css']
})


export class BmicalculatorComponent implements OnInit {

  public parameters: ParametersDto = new ParametersDto;
  public result: number = 0.0;
  public text: string = "Default text";
  public results: Results = new Results();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  sendRequest() {
    this.http.post<Results>('https://localhost:44431/' + 'bmicalculator' + '/calc', this.parameters,
      { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Tye', 'application/json') }).
      subscribe(response => {
        this.results = response;
        this.result = this.results.Result;

    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
}
```

Below is a class Result I expect to receive:

```
export class Results {
  public Classification: BMIClassification = 1;
  public Result: number = 0.0;
  public Summary: string = "";
}

enum BMIClassification {
  Underweight,
  Normal,
  Overweight,
  Obesity,
  ExtremeObesity
}
```

Here is class of result that controller returns:

```
public class BMIResult
    {
        public BMIClassification? BMIClassification { get; set; }
        public double Result { get; set; }
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is enum used in the class above

```
public enum BMIClassification
    {
        Underweight,
        Normal,
        Overweight,
        Obesity,
        ExtremeObesity
    }
```

Most probably, I messed up sth with in the Typescript, but I don't know where... Please give me any hint ! :)

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

I changed slightly the way how I read result and it worked :) Code below

```
  sendRequest() {
    this.http.post<Results>('https://localhost:44431/' + 'bmicalculator' + '/calc', this.parameters).
      subscribe(response => {
        this.result = (response as any).result;

    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
}
```